# Did ancient Romans raise the intonation of their voices when asking questions?

Tags: classical-latin, spoken-language

I understand that in Classical Latin, when someone asks a question, the *-ne* causes stress patterns for some words to be modified, so that both the *-ne* and the new stress pattern indicates that the sentence is a question.

However, are those the only commonly used indicators of a question?  Do scholars know if a final rise in intonation was also used to indicate a question, as is the case in many modern languages?

Comment: Do you know what words Romans used to describe intonation? It would be easy (in principle at least) to search a digital corpus for an ancient text on the topic if one just has some keywords (if the keywords are not too common otherwise).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Unfortunately I don't.

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to do a full search, but I think *vox* can be used this way (Lewis and Short gives one example from Cicero, it seems to me from first glance).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no clear evidence - we simply don't know.

Harm Pinkster (Pinkster 2015) writes that even though there may have been something comparable to the falling or rising tone known from many languages, including English,

> we are not able to recover much information about Latin intonation (p. 15).

Pinkster mentions (in a footnote) that ancient grammarians and rhetoricians were interested in intonation (vox) but, as Hannah Rosen observes, "it it scarcely possible to describe them lucidly" (Rosen 2009: 337). Here are some examples she cites:

"Vocis mutationes totidem sunt quot animorum" (Cicero, Orator, 55)

"Quare, **et quia nemo de ea re diligenter scripsit**—nam omnes vix posse putarunt de voce et vultu et gestu dilucide scribi, cum eae res ad sensus nostros pertinerent—et quia magnopere ea pars a nobis ad dicendum conparanda est, non neglegenter videtur tota res consideranda." (Rhetorica ad Herennium, 3,19)

Here's a very revealing passage (Rhetorica ad Herennium, 4,54) illustrating their attitude towards serious study of intonation:

[image]

**References:**

Pinkster, Harm. 2015. *The Oxford Latin syntax. Volume 1: The simple clause*. Oxford: Oxford University Press. (**highly recommend** - the best Latin grammar!)

Rosen, Hannah. 2009. *Coherence, sentence modification, and sentence-part modification - the contribution of particles*. In Baldi, Philip, and Pierluigi Cuzzolin, eds., New perspectives on historical Latin syntax. Volume 1. Syntax of the sentence, pp. 317-442. Berlin: Mouton de Gruyter.