# In which cases the enclitic -ne is optional, and and in which is it mandatory?

Tags: enclitic, interrogative

As I get it, -ne is used to play the role of a question word when there's no question word, and of course, when it's a yes-no question.

But is it good practice to omit it in such questions?
Is it a formal/unformal thing, or an hypercorrection thing?
In general, when is it mandatory and when is it optional to use it?

Comment: Let's see if there is a more informed answer, but [Romans had no question mark](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/did-the-romans-have-a-question-mark), hence a question word seems mandatory in writing (be it -ne, num, numquid). Regarding spoken Latin, [we don't know](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/245/did-ancient-romans-raise-the-intonation-of-their-voices-when-asking-questions) whether there was a difference in intonation for questions, which would render _markers_ unnecessary.

Comment: Has anyone made the argument that because a rise in intonation is present in so many descendant languages of Latin that it could mean that this was also present in classical Latin itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To state a question (direct or indirect) in Classical and Medieval Latin, you always need a question marker. These can be either:

- interrogative pronouns or adjectives (e.g. *Quis venit?*, *In quae via ambulat?*, *Per quod medium probas?*, etc.),
- interrogative adverbs (e.g. *Ubi estis?*, *Quousque tandem abutere?*, *Num venit?*, *Quaesivi ne indices*, *Quaesitum utrum Deus sit trinus*, etc.)
- The enclitic interrogative article "-nĕ" (weakened from "nē"); also "nonne".

However, Early Latin exhibits total interrogatives without question markers:

- Redis tu tandem? (Plaut.)
- Tu id nunc refers? (Plaut.)

(Note that question marks, and punctuation in general, was a later Medieval development---historically derived from musical pneumas, rather than pragmatic cues---and cannot be understood as interrogative markers proper.)

So, to answer your question: "standard" Classical Latin (what you learn in school) and Medieval Latin always require interrogative markers. Still, not all markers are identical (e.g. *Num* presupposes a negative answer, *-nĕ* doesn't presuppose any answer, *quando* requires a temporally framed answer, and so on), so you must  choose well your interrogatives. In sum, "Edisti?" is bad Latin. "Edistine?" is fine.

---

**Update**

For those seeking a more "authorative" answer, see e.g.:

- Guildersleeve's *Latin Grammar* (3rd ed., 1903), §§ 453–68, 558 (available here: https://archive.org/details/gildersleeveslat00gild)
- Allen and Greenough's *New Latin Grammar* (1903), §§ 330–5 (available here: https://archive.org/details/allengreenoughsn01alle)
- Bassols de Climens, *Sintaxis latina* (1971), II, §§ 32–40 (available here: https://archive.org/details/SINTAXISLATINA2MARIANOBASSOLSDECLIMENT)
- J. Schrickx, "Polar Questions in Latin with and without the Enclitic Particle -ne", in *Pragmatic Approaches to Latin and Ancient Greek*, eds. C. Denizot & O. Spevac. Amsterdam / Philadelphia: John Benjamins(2017), pp.235–55

Comment: Would you consider it fair to translate "Edistine?" as "Have you eaten?" and "Edisti?" as "You have eaten?!"? In the modern languages I know you can always have a question without question markers, but then the tone is quite different (which I attempted to convey with "?!").

Comment: The first one is OK, but the second one isn't customary, and thus it doesn't seem proper.

Comment: +1, but could you add some authoritative source(s) to support the argument?

Comment: Calling Plautus "bad Latin" because his usage disagrees with your school grammar is a bit of a stretch, don't you think?

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I did not notice anything of the sort in the answer. I only noticed calling it Early Latin.

Comment: So, "pin quam pridem non **edisti**?" is bad Latin then?

Comment: @VladimirF Read the two last sentences.

Comment: @NVaughan Let me quote the first sentence from your last source's abstract: "The Latin enclitic particle -ne, which may be of an affirmative origin, is an 
optional focusing particle of polar questions, which in Latin can also occur 
without any particle."